# null pointer exception in java when coding

Tags: java

I am a newbie in objective programming so forgive me if this question is dumb.

I am developing a small to-do program as a exercise. But when I try to load existing txt file & folders for task storage, IDE told me `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`.
I read the popular one from this site describing this error, I kinda understood why it happened, but I just coudn't find the problem.

Line 17-26 of ListProcess:

```
public ListItem[] loadList() throws FileNotFoundException {
        ListItem[] listitem = new ListItem[200];
        int listCount=0;
        for (String txts : loadTxtsList()) {
            File file = new File(txts);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner("List/"+file);
            listitem[listCount].isFolder = false;
            listitem[listCount].name = txts.replace(".txt", "");
            listitem[listCount].description = scanner.nextLine();
            int i = scanner.nextInt();
```

and yes, I'm using a class called ListItem to store these tasks.

ListItem class:

```
public class ListItem {
    boolean isFolder=false;
    String name;
    String description;
    String[] tags = new String[10];
    Status status;
}
```

Comment: If you re-read the "popular answer" it'll give you the tools to find the problem. Then the next time you get an `NPE` you'll know how to find the root of the problem and solve it yourself. The stacktrace tells you which line causes the exception, so you can track which variable is `null`. Your question doesn't contain the line number, so at least edit the question to include the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line:

```
ListItem[] listitem = new ListItem[200];
```

creates an array whose items are all `null`.